# Symfony Doctrine ORM CLI Font/Colors not working?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I have been looking online to see how to fix this, and have been unsuccessful. I've actually had this issue for over a year now and have simply just ignored it. Now that I'm doing more doctrine ORM stuff in my Symfony 4.1 project, I would like to know if anyone knows how to fix the font/colors on my Windows 10 machine?

Command Line tools:
* Powershell - Doesn't show the colors correctly
* Command Prompt - Doesn't show the colors correctly
* Git CMD - Doesn't show the colors correctly

This is what my CLI looks like when i'm making or editing an entity:

```
E:\wamp\www\GasCruiter>php bin/console make:entity



 Class name of the entity to create or update (e.g. GentleChef):
 > UserConfirmation
U[K7[30;47mser[39;49m8s[K7[30;47mer[39;49m8e[K7[30;47mr[39;49m8r[K78C[K7[30;47monfirmation[39;49m8o[K7[30;47mnfirmation[39;49m8n[K7[30;47mfirmation[39;49m8f[K7[30;47mirmation[39;49m8i[K7[30;47mrmation[39;49m8r[K7[30;47mmation[39;49m8m[K7[30;47mation[39;49m8a[K7[30;47mtion[39;49m8t[K7[30;47mion[39;49m8i[K7[30;47mon[39;49m8o[K7[30;47mn[39;49m8n[K78

 Your entity already exists! So let's add some new fields!

 [32mNew property name (press [39m[32m<return>[39m[32m to stop adding fields)[39m:
 > date

 [32mField type (enter [39m[33m?[39m[32m to see all types)[39m [[33mstring[39m]:
 > datetime
d[K7[30;47matetime[39;49m8a[K7[30;47mtetime[39;49m8t[K7[30;47metime[39;49m8e[K7[30;47mtime[39;49m8t[K7[30;47mime[39;49m8i[K7[30;47mme[39;49m8m[K7[30;47me[39;49m8e[K78

 [32mCan this field be null in the database (nullable) (yes/no)[39m [[33mno[39m]:
 > no

 [32mupdated[39m: src/Entity/UserConfirmation.php

 [32mAdd another property? Enter the property name (or press [39m[32m<return>[39m[32m to stop adding fields)[39m:
 >


 [37;42m          [39;49m
 [37;42m Success! [39;49m
 [37;42m          [39;49m

 Next: When you're ready, create a migration with [33mmake:migration[39m
```

I must be missing some sort of system font? Not exactly sure how to fix this.

Comment: These are ANSI escape codes, I guess Windows' terminal is too dumb to understand them, or possibly just not configured properly. I've not used Symfony directly, but you'd want to look for some way to disable them in the help. For example in Composer, there's a `--no-ansi` option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither the **Powershell** nor **CMD** terminals/console emulators support ANSI escape codes for colors.

This is why you're seeing these [**ANSI escape codes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). Your terminal just doesn't know how to interpret them.

While I personally haven't used windows for a while I remember that I had good experience with **[ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/)**. It's brings color support amongst other nice features.

For a quick start you should give **[cmder](http://cmder.net/)** a shot - it's a ready-to-go console emulator with a nice color scheme built on top of ConEmu.

Another quick option to get a console emulator with color support is to download **[CygWin](https://www.cygwin.com/)** which gives you a POSIX compatible environment on windows and use i.e. the included port of **xterm**.

Further any tool based on `symfony/console` accepts the `--no-ansi` flag to suppress output of ANSII escape codes.

Examples without color output:

```
 bin/console --no-ansi make:entity
 composer --no-ansi install
```